# Java FX: How to change the style of a cell when a property of the object relating to a row changes in TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablerow, tablecell

Currently, I'm trying to learn how to use `TableView`, but I can't handle the behavior of cells properly. Here is my problem:

I have a `TableView` with several rows, each one displaying some information about a certain instance of `Point` (a homemade class). This `TableView` is composed of several columns (each one representing a property of my class `Point`).

I would like to bind the background color of cells to a `BooleanProperty` field of my class `Point`, such that, when this `BooleanProperty` changes, the background color of a cell, associated to the row representing the instance of `Point` that sees its `BooleanProperty` field being changed, is modified.

For this purpose, I tried the following code:

```
myColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Point, Double>, TableCell<Point, Double>>() {
        public TextFieldTableCell<Point, Double> call(TableColumn<Point, Double> param) {
            TextFieldTableCell<Point, Double> myCell  = new TextFieldTableCell<Point, Double>(new DoubleStringConverter() {
                public Double fromString(String str) {
                    Double x;
                    try {
                        x = Double.parseDouble(str);
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        x = myTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getFx();
                    }
                    return x;   
                }
            });
            myCell.tableRowProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TableRow>() {
                  @Override
                  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TableRow> ov, TableRow oldVal,
                      TableRow newVal) {
                      if (newVal != null) {
                          if (newVal.getItem() != null) {
                              ((Point) newVal.getItem()).myBooleanProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                                @Override
                                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue,
                                        Boolean newValue) {
                                    if (newValue) {
                                        myCell.setStyle("");
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        myCell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFD48A;");
                                    }

                                }

                              });
                          }
                      }
                  }
                });
            return myCell;
        }
    });
```

My principal problem was to access the instance of `Point` relating to the row containing the cell `myCell`. Indeed, `myCell.getTableRow()` returned `null`, so I couldn't just use `((Point) myCell.getTableRow().getItem())`.
Therefore, I used a listener on `tableRowProperty` of `myCell` in order to access my instance of `Point` when `myCell.getTableRow()` doesn't return `null` anymore.

This code works properly until some rows are removed. Indeed, some parts of the entire code (not shown here) allow to remove some rows (I just call `remove(int index)` on the list `ObservableList<Point>` from which my `TableView` is built). After the deletion of the row, there is a problem:

For example, if the first row of the table has a colored cell in `myColumn` and is deleted, then the former second row becomes the first row, but its cell in `myColumn` becomes colored even if it wasn't before the deletion.

Moreover, if I sort the table, the positions of the colored cells are not modified.

In short, it seems that the fact of a cell to be colored is bound to the index of its row in the table, instead of the `BooleanProperty` of the instance of `Point` associated to the row.

So, I understand that my code is not correct and I would like to know how it can be changed or replace.

Thank you for reading this and for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply rely on CSS "magic" instead to come up with code that does not require you to navigate though a "property hierarchy" of depth 3. (You never remove any listeners BTW which means even properties of items no longer associated with the table row update the cells and even scrolling will result in this behavior.)

#### CSS stylesheet

```css
.table-row-cell:no-my-boolean .table-cell {
    -fx-background-color: #FFD48A;
}
```

#### Java code

```
PseudoClass pseudoClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("no-my-boolean");
myTable.setRowFactory(t -> new TableRow<Point>() {
    private final ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (o, v, newValue) -> {
        pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudoClass, !newValue);
    };

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Point item, boolean empty) {
        // remove listener from old item
        Point oldItem = getItem();
        if (oldItem != null) {
            oldItem.myBooleanProperty().removeListener(listener);
        }

        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item == null) {
             pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudoClass, false);
        } else {
             pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudoClass, !item.getMyBoolean());
             item.myBooleanProperty().addListener(listener);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This code works properly, except for a small detail: when the BooleanProperty become true, all the row is colored and not only the cell belonging to the column. Actually, I've got three columns which can have colored cells and each one of these columns is linked to a BooleanProperty in the Point class (so I have three BooleanProperty in that class). Do you know how I can adapt the code to this case? Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your cell factory for each column you could do something like below:

```
@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    styleProperty().bind(
        Bindings.when(
            Bindings.selectBoolean(
                tableRowProperty(), 
                "item.myBoolean")
            ).then("-fx-background-color: #FFD48A;")
             .otherwise("")
    );  
}
```

Above is just a guess and may be incorrect (I didn't compile it or try it).

Comment: I tried your code and some problems disappear :). I just have some warnings like this 

Jan 30, 2018 7:56:06 AM com.sun.javafx.binding.SelectBinding$SelectBindingHelper getObservableValue
WARNING: Exception while evaluating select-binding [item, myBoolean]

and some cells that remain colored after the deletion of the row...
Thank you for this help anyway!

Comment: Oh well, this was just a guess.  Fabian's solution looks promising, try that :-)